# Fortran, how to merge(unit) 2 arrays into new 1 which contents unique elements from previous

Tags: arrays, fortran

I have to compare two arrays, and get a new one as a result of comparison. Which has uncommon elements for two arrays at the same time.(prefer using reg. programming)

```
program arrays
implicit none
integer, parameter :: m = 5
integer i, j
integer :: a(1:5)
integer :: b(1:5)
!integer :: g(!) - new array

a=[1,2,33,44,5]
b=[3,2,44,7,33]

print *,'Check for common numbers'
forall ( i = 1:m, j =1:m, a(i) /= b(j)) ! think i need something like this

end forall
!result should be g=[1,5,3,7]
end program
```

I tried other method but it has mistakes in logic and get other results(think dont need it)

```
program try
implicit none
integer :: example(12)         ! The input
integer :: res(size(example))  ! The output
integer :: k                   ! The number of unique elements
integer :: i, j
integer :: a(6)
integer :: b(6)
integer :: c(12)

a = [3,6,1,6,-1,2]
b = [4,5,1,-7,2,1]

forall(i=1:6)
example(i) = a(i)
end forall 

forall(i=7:12)
example(i) = b(i-6)
end forall ! merge 2 arrays into 1, for searching unique combinations

k = 1
res(1) = example(1)
outer: do i=2,size(example)
 do j=1,k
    if (res(j) == example(i)) then
       ! Found a match so start looking again
       cycle outer
    end if
 end do
 ! No match found so add it to the output
 k = k + 1
 res(k) = example(i)
 end do outer
 print *, example ! get 3,6,1,-1, 2, 4, 5, -7(Of course!) except 3, 6, -1, 4, 5, -7
 write(*,advance='no',fmt='(a,i0,a)') 'Unique list has ',k,' elements: '
 write(*,*) res(1:k)
 end program try
```

Comment: What is "reg. programming"?

Comment: Using forall for example instead of do circle. Using Masks, and Arrays fortran functions instead of circles.

Comment: If you do not want to compare each number with every number in the other array, I guess, you need to sort them first. I don't think you get this more efficiently solved with a forall here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
rslt = [ PACK(arr1,ALL(SPREAD(arr1,1,SIZE(arr2))/=SPREAD(arr2,2,SIZE(arr1)),dim=1)), &
         PACK(arr2,ALL(SPREAD(arr1,1,SIZE(arr2))/=SPREAD(arr2,2,SIZE(arr1)),dim=2)) ]
```

will, given two rank-1 integer arrays called `arr1` and `arr2`, assign to `rslt` the union of the differences `arr1\arr2` and `arr2\arr1`.  Note:

- Not an explicit loop in sight, but don't be surprised if the compiler generates a lot.
- This expression `SPREAD(arr1,1,SIZE(arr2))/=SPREAD(arr2,2,SIZE(arr1))` is duplicated so probably computed twice; for production code you'd probably want to do something about that.
- That same expression consumes memory, so you'd definitely not want to duplicate it.
- Sorting not required.
- Me, I'd use loops.